# Copying contents of one vault to another

Tags: azure, copy, move, azure-backup-vault

Somewhere I read that I can copy backups from one vault to another. I have been unable to find anything leading me in the right direction.

My intent is to do so, so that I can work around the fact that one cannot rename vaults, once they have been created.

I have been all over the different vault options, but have not come across anything suggesting that I was on the right path.

Comment: hey does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-move-recovery-services-vault) help?

Answer (score 1):

This answer have been copied from [How To Copy All Secrets From One KeyVault To Another In Azure](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-copy-all-secrets-from-one-azure-keyvault-to-another-azure-keyva)

There are two options to make it:

1. Copy Azure KeyVault using the Powershell script
2. Copy Azure KeyVault using Azure CLI

Here, we are copying 4 secrets from the source keyvault called **myKeyVault2020** for the demonstrations.

[image]

**Option 1: Copy Azure KeyVault using Powershell script**

Now we want to copy secrets that are not already present in the destination keyvault called **kv-myapps-2021** using Azure Powershell.

[image]

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$sourceKvName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$destKvName
)
Connect-AzAccount
$secretNames = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceKvName).Name
$secretNames.foreach{
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $destKvName -Name $_ `
        -SecretValue (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceKvName -Name $_).SecretValue
}
```

We can see that all secrets have been copied successfully to **kv-myapps-2021**.

[image]

**Option 2: Copy Azure KeyVault using Azure CLI**

We can also copy all secrets using the below Bash script to a new destination keyvault called **kv-myapps-2023**.

[image]

```
Source_Kv_Name="myKeyVault2020"
Dest_Kv_Name="kv-myapps-2023"
SECRETS+=($(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $Source_Kv_Name --query "[].id" -o tsv))
for SECRET in "${SECRETS[@]}"; do
SECRETNAME=$(echo "$SECRET" | sed 's|.*/||')
SECRET_CHECK=$(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $Dest_Kv_Name --query "[?name=='$SECRETNAME']" -o tsv)
if [ -n "$SECRET_CHECK" ]
then
    echo "$SECRETNAME already exists in $Dest_Kv_Name"
else
     echo "Copying $SECRETNAME from Source KeyVault: $Source_Kv_Name to Destination KeyVault: $Dest_Kv_Name"
    SECRET=$(az keyvault secret show --vault-name $Source_Kv_Name -n $SECRETNAME --query "value" -o tsv)
    az keyvault secret set --vault-name $Dest_Kv_Name -n $SECRETNAME --value "$SECRET" >/dev/null
fi
done
```

Let’s check the destination key vault. Awesome! All secrets are copied.